# Converting string with decimal to double using atof in C++

Tags: c++, string, atof, c-strings

In my program im trying to read in a file with money like this "$876,725.38" I was able to remove the comma and dollar sign and I am now trying to convert the string to a double using atof but the issue im having now is after printing `MONEYS` after the conversion I get everything before the period on majority of these, but some with less than 6 digits before the period do print either one or two digits after the period. If anyone has a solution to this it would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to C++ and need help. Thanks!

MAIN ISSUE: Converting from string to double, the data after decimal does not print.

```
    void readFile()
{
    string line, nuMoney, munney, cents;
    unsigned long dollarSign, period;


    ifstream myfile("MONEY.txt");

    int numLines = countLines("MONEY.txt");
    //cout << "NUMLINES: " << numLines << endl;

    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: File could not be opened." << endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < numLines-1; i++)
    {
        getline(myfile, line, '\n');
        dollarSign = line.find('$');
        period = line.find('.');

        line.erase (remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ','), line.end()); //remove commas

        munney = line.substr(dollarSign+1);
        //cout << munney << endl;

        //cents = line.substr(period);
        //cout << "Cents: " << cents << endl;

        //double CENTUS = atof(cents.c_str());
        //cout << "CENTUS: " << CENTUS << endl;

        double MONEYS = atof(munney.c_str());
        cout << MONEYS << endl;

        list<double> acct;
        acct.push_back(MONEYS);

    }

}
```

sample output:

```
937380
404261
814158
30218.1
69340.1
479891
517241
7203.55
975619
59219.4
900052
539774
336799
347700
532466
83496.8
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please!! Inputs, expected outputs and completly compilable code that reproduces the unexpected behavior.

Comment: sooo… what's the problem? I don't understand, your description is unclear…

Comment: Storing monetary values as floating points numbers is a really bad idea. Is that a requirement?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant sorry for the bad description... I'm really just having an issue after converting my string to a double. When I print out the double it prints everything before the period but I need it all in order to add it up. Hope that makes some more sense.

Comment: @stefan no, whats the better solution?

Comment: @JohnnyTran An integer. Just use cents as a unit, not dollars.

Comment: Instead you can use an `int` multiply by 100 to include "cents," divide by 100 to get the monetary value.

Comment: @EvanCarslake what do you mean by 'multiply by 100' ?

Comment: @stefan what if I was trying to take the whole value like '123456.78'. The `cents` was something I was testing and why its commented out. I really want to keep the whole value together and put it in a STD::LIST after.

Comment: Take the amount `4.50` as an int so multiply `4.50 * 100 = 450`. Then to convert back `450 / 100 = 4.50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell the output stream that you want a fixed precision of 2 digits after the dot:

```
#include <iomanip>
// ...
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << MONEYS << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point (`float`, `double` and `long double`) aren't great for storing exact values.  They are great because they make it easy to do lots of different math on a wide range of values, but there are many values which can't be represented exactly using IEEE floating points.  Values as simple as `0.1` can't be exactly expressed by the type, but the input and output routines often round to make it seem like they are handled correctly.

To store decimal perfect values I suggest treating the 2 parts of the value as separate integers when reading in, converting the fractional point based on how many digits after the decimal place were read in, and then doing a little bit of math to convert both pieces into a single integer.  For US money the LSB (least significant bit) of this integer may represent 1 cent (unless fractional cents need to be represented accurately).  A similar approach can be used for outputting the values.

Comment: thank you, im not really sure the math bit to convert the 2 pieces into a single int. Some more insight into that please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's due to default precision of cout stream for floating point values: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/